# Am I maxing out possible data insert

Tags: php, mysql

I have a process that opens 60 Iframe windows per server, that each does part of the task. 
The mysql tables are not indexed, the data is being inserted 1000 rows at a time in a bulk insert (first written to a temp memory created in each frame then bulk offloaded to the hd table). This is processing 1.5 billion rows of data per table, that is being written to by the 60 frames running of a 32 core 128g ram server, it maxes out the server cpu to 99-100% for 6 - 7 hrs.  I have 3 servers processing this task, and 1 more with 24 drives on raid as the db server, that it's only running 6 - 15% cpu load to manage mysql (5.0.67) .  Where could the bottleneck be happening that going from 1 to 3 servers processing the data, doesn't increase the "total" data written?  Each of the 3 is writing to 1 db table, table locks are minimal, that I could flip it to each frame writes to 1 table eliminating locks but I don't think this is where the issue is considering 180 connections continual write only amounts to 5 - 10 locks per second. Removing indexing did speed up the write speed considerably, (I'll have to deal with that once all data is written).  Is there a mysql value / option / ? that would improve this, I have 160 more tables to create ? I wish I could use Ram tables, but the data alone is 33 gig for each table and mysql 5.0.67 wont do that, does anyone thing that switching to 5.6 be a huge difference ?  I'm stumped, mysql says it's writing on avg 47 mb / s, key efficiency = 100%, query cache hitrate = 93 - 100%.  Any help is much appreciated thank you all for any input.

Comment: you didn't mention what table type your using, also what exactly are you doing having iframes write to the database with no user facing it. don't you have a better alternative to do this

Comment: Type: MyISAM, Format: Fixed, Index Length: 1.00 KB (1,024), Data Length: 31.49 GB (33,812,861,867), Max Data Length: 5888.00 TB.  I user the iframes to process small data comparisons (a being 1, stock matrix a vs 12,000, b vs 11,999, etc = 143 M comparisons x 22 days for 1 month) .  The bottleneck became apparent when I set the task to multiple servers, that the "TOTAL DATA" written did not increase of any value even with each server writing to a different table.

Comment: For example:

1 Server processing, could write 800,000,000 rows in 3 hrs to 1 table

2 Servers processing, could write 400,000,000 rows in 3 hrs to 2 tables (1 dedicated per server)

I'm wondering if I've reached the max ability of MySQL, since the network or HD are far from being maxed out for their potential.

Answer (score 2):

Do you open 60 iframes at the same time?

This means all processes are parallel. Things do not get faster like this, instead they slow down.

Somewhere the bottleneck is related to read the table from the disk. Multiplying concurrent disk access is slowing down everything. Not even to talk about simultaneaus longrunning queries, that may block each other in the DB server.

Compare the 47 Mb/s written to these values:

- SATA I max theoretical throughput 150Mb/s
- Network at 1000 Gbps: max theoretical throughput 125Mb/s

You are close to both

Comment: Each frame is processing on an individual url  1.local to 60.local (server 1 from server 1) and same for each machine, opening 1 url waiting for it to complete, then opening the next actually is hugely slower for the total run.  Only using 18% of my network total, actually using the multiple urls fools things into believing the request is coming from 60 unique requests. I wonder if using symbolic MySQL on each of the 3 processing servers could be the solution, and the bottleneck is 1 MySQL just can't manage that much thruput.

Comment: Lorenz, 24 high end drives on raid, that read/write numbers are about 20x+ that, think I benched them at around 3600 Mb/s , multiple (4) network cards in each server as well using nic teaming = at peek 18% network usage.  On historical performance, the Peek Traffic value was 232.5 mb/s

Comment: I admit such hardware is beyond my experience.